# File Type dependent key mapping valid only for that specific filetype

Tags: key-bindings

I am aware that you can either use an `Autocommand` or defining a key-binding in some `ftplugin` file.

However, once the key-binding is defined, it will stay, no matter the filetype.

However, imagine that I want the mapping `nnoremap <F12> <cmd>echo "Hello"` be valid only for `python` filetypes, how shall I do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> how shall I do?

You shall read the relevant documentation, `:help :map-buffer`:

```
If the first argument to one of these commands is "<buffer>" the mapping will
be effective in the current buffer only.  Example:
        :map <buffer>  ,w  /[.,;]<CR>
Then you can map ",w" to something else in another buffer:
        :map <buffer>  ,w  /[#&!]<CR>
```

"But how do I get there if I don't know what to search for?" you might ask. Well, you get there by:

1. figuring out that you need help with *mapping*,
2. asking *Vim* for help with `:help mapping`,
3. and looking around. The relevant section is only 200 lines in.

That is, if you missed the "ADDITIONALLY..." section in `:help usr_40`.

The solution, in short…

1. Create `ftplugin/python.vim` (or `after/ftplugin/python.vim` if you want it to be sourced *after* the built-in one).
2. Add `nnoremap <buffer> <F12> <cmd>echo "Hello"<CR>` to it.